# Custom Data Validation requiring a numerical 00-00 format

Tags: data-validation

I would like to restrict the data in a cell to a numberical 00-00 format with the following requirements:

1. The first and fourth characters need to begin with a "0" or a "1"
2. A hyphen needs to appear as the 3rd character

Can anyone help with this Custom Data Validation formula?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but one (rather brute-force) way would be to just check for that particular pattern with a formula.

You'll need `ISNUMBER()` to check for numbers<sup>*</sup>, and you'll need `MID(A1,x,1)` to check the character at the *x*th position in cell `A1`.

Combine these with an `AND()` and you're good to go.

For the particular example in the OP you can use:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MID(C4,1,1)*1),ISNUMBER(MID(C4,2,1)*1),MID(C4,3,1)="-",ISNUMBER(MID(C4,4,1)*1),ISNUMBER(MID(C4,5,1)*1))
```

*<sup>*</sup> Checking for numbers in text doesn't work by default. See [this SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/589598/315715) for how to resolve that.*

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your Data Validation custom formula:

```
=AND(MID(A1, 3, 1)="-",
     OR(MID(A1, 1, 1)="0",
        MID(A1, 1, 1)="1"),
     OR(MID(A1, 4, 1)="0",
        MID(A1, 4, 1)="1"))
```

Basically what you want involves three conditions that must be met:

1. The third character must be a hyphen.
2. The first character must be a `0` or `1`
3. The fourth character must be a `0` or `1`

If you want, you can add this to the `AND` to ensure that the input limited to five (5) characters only.

```
LEN(A1)=5
```

And don't forget you must format the cell as `TEXT`, else it will *always* be translated to date (although I suspect what you want is date format too)

Comment: Hey, sorry, we overlapped.

Comment: Thank you to you both, your responses are much appreciated. This is my first time using this site and I couldn't be happier with the results. Thanks again! @LondonRob

Comment: @Whitney That's what this site is all about. If you like the answers, think about upvoting and accepting (clicking the check mark!)