# Regex on Excel or similar solution?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex, csv

I have an excel sheet I need to sanitise. I have over 1000 addresses and for some random reason, the data sent over by the supplier has random 16 digits at the start of the street address

Not all of them though.

Can I write a formula of sorts to strip the first 16 digits if they exist in the format

xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

Data is like this

```
0123 4567 8910 1234 1 Lovely Road (1 Lovely Road)
2 Lovely Road
0123 4567 8910 1234 11 Another Road (11 Another Road)
```

Comment: In Excel, you cannot use Regex in worksheet formulas unless you write a UDF.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that A1 contains the address then a simple solution would be:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1, 20), " ", "")*1), MID(A1, 21, LEN(A1)), A1)
```

It's not perfect (for example the position of the spaces is irrelevant) but should hopefully work for most of the data.

### How it works

To show how this works, we'll be breaking down the formula and placing each component in a cell starting with A1 containing the string.

In B1 you want to get the 20 left most characters:

```
=LEFT(A1, 20)
```

In C1 you want to replace the spaces:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1, " ", "")
```

In D1 you need to check if it's a number using `ISNUMBER` - however that will return `False` if it's a string containing a number. So we can work around that by multiplying by 1 ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/589597/check-if-excel-cell-text-is-numeric-using-formula-only)):

```
=ISNUMBER(C1*1)
```

So now D1 contains `True` or `False` depending on whether or not we have a set of numbers at the beginning of the string.

So for E1 we just have an `If` which checks if `D1` is `True` and, if so, displays everything in `A1` from position 21 onwards. If `D1` is `False` then E1 just displays the entire contents of `A1`:

```
=IF(D1, MID(A1, 21, LEN(A1)), A1)
```